# How to add dynamic data in source of html using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dynamic

I am using a simple Javascript toggle function with the following code.

```
<script>
function add_more(){
if (document.form.more[0].checked==true)
{

document.getElementById('moreTxt').style.display="block";

}

else if (document.form.more[1].checked==true)
{

document.getElementById('moreTxt').style.display="none";
}
}
</script>


do want to enter something more ? 
<form name="form">
<input type="radio" value="yes" name="more" onclick="add_more()" /> Yes
<input type="radio" value="No" name="more" onclick="add_more()" /> No
<div id="moreTxt" style="display:none">
hi you can enter more here 
<textarea rows="3" cols="4">
</textarea>
</div>
</form>
```

The Problem is if I click on 'yes', and for some reason I refresh the page, then the 'yes' radio button remains checked but `moreTxt div` hides (i.e. its default visiblity mode).

How should I tackle this problem?

Comment: Why don't you pass true or false as parameter to your add_more() function? Does the page refresh when you click yes or when you manually refresh the page after you 've clicked yes?

Comment: I don't see what's wrong: http://jsfiddle.net/GSg2q/

Comment: my code is working fine, what i want is, using javascript. i write anything in my html page, but that doesn't show in source of the page, i want to pass this dada into database, and data from this div is not going properly

Comment: In short, i want to preserve the state of radio button even though the page refreshes. Problem is, when the page refreshes all elements are set to its default attributes, same case with the moreTxt div, it goes to hidden and the radio button of yes is still checked

Answer (score 1):

Check the value of the control on document ready and adjust the div visibility accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

This will reset all your input on load:

```
<script>
function resetChkBox() {
    var e=document.getElementsByTagName('input');
    var i=0;
    while(i<e.length) {
        if(e[i++].type=='radio') {
            e[i].checked=false;
        }
    }
}
</script>


  <body onload="resetChkBox()">
```

Comment: If its done this way then the statefulness provided by the browser will be hurt. If there is a situation where the page is loaded due to some server postbacks , then this will be a bad case.

Answer (score 0):

you should perform you add_more function onDucomentReady
Assuming you're using jquery:

```
       $(document).ready(function() {
         add_more(); 
       }
       )
```

or use plain javascript equivalent of document.ready()

Answer (score 0):

If this is to be performed without jquery which should be the case since including jquery for such small thing will be overkill :

```
document.attachEvent("onDOMContentLoaded", function(){
    ready()
  });
```

In ready function check the value of the radio button.